# group by per day pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame :

From id  To id Price  Date

```
a         b    20     30/05/2019
b         c    5      30/05/2019
c         a    20     30/05/2019
a         d    10     02/06/2019
d         c    5      02/06/2019

id  Name  
a   Claudia
b   Manuella
c   remy
d   Paul
```

The output that i want is :

```
Date         Name   current balance 
30/05/2019   Claudia       0
30/05/2019   Manuella      15
30/05/2019   Remy         -15
30/05/2019   Paul           0
02/06/2019   Claudia      -10
02/06/2019   Manuella      15
02/06/2019   Remy         -10
02/06/2019   Paul           5
```

I want to get  the current balance in each day for all users.

my idea is to  make a groupby per user and calculate the sum of the TO column minus the From column. But how to do it per day? especially it's cumulative and not per day?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a bit of an effort to get the requirements right. Here's my version of the solution.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [
        ("a","b",20,"30/05/2019"),
        ("b","c",5 ,"30/05/2019"),
        ("c","a",20,"30/05/2019"),
        ("a","d",10,"02/06/2019"),
        ("d","c",5 ,"02/06/2019"),
      ]

df1Columns = ["From_Id", "To_Id", "Price",  "Date"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)
df1 = df1.withColumn("Date",F.to_date(F.to_timestamp("Date", 'dd/MM/yyyy')).alias('Date'))
print("Actual initial data")
df1.show(truncate=False)


data2 = [
        ("a","Claudia"),
        ("b","Manuella"),
        ("c","Remy"),
        ("d","Paul"),
      ]

df2Columns = ["id","Name"]
df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema = df2Columns)


print("Actual initial data")
df2.show(truncate=False)

alldays_df = df1.select("Date").distinct().repartition(20)
allusers_df = df2.select("id").distinct().repartition(10)

crossjoin_df = alldays_df.crossJoin(allusers_df)
crossjoin_df = crossjoin_df.withColumn("initial", F.lit(0))
crossjoin_df = crossjoin_df.withColumnRenamed("id", "common_id").cache()
crossjoin_df.show(n=40, truncate=False)



from_sum_df = df1.groupby("Date", "From_Id").agg(F.sum("Price").alias("from_sum"))
from_sum_df = from_sum_df.withColumnRenamed("From_Id", "common_id")
from_sum_df.show(truncate=False)

from_sum_df = crossjoin_df.alias('cross').join(
    from_sum_df.alias('from'), ['Date', 'common_id'], how='outer'
).select('Date', 'common_id',
    F.coalesce('from.from_sum', 'cross.initial').alias('from_amount') ).cache()
from_sum_df.show(truncate=False)


to_sum_df = df1.groupby("Date", "To_Id").agg(F.sum("Price").alias("to_sum"))
to_sum_df = to_sum_df.withColumnRenamed("To_Id", "common_id")
to_sum_df.show(truncate=False)

to_sum_df = crossjoin_df.alias('cross').join(
    to_sum_df.alias('to'), ['Date', 'common_id'], how='outer'
).select('Date', 'common_id',
    F.coalesce('to.to_sum', 'cross.initial').alias('to_amount') ).cache()
to_sum_df.show(truncate=False)

joined_df = to_sum_df.join(from_sum_df, ["Date", "common_id"], how='inner')
joined_df.show(truncate=False)

balance_df = joined_df.withColumn("balance", F.col("to_amount") - F.col("from_amount"))
balance_df.show(truncate=False)

final_df = balance_df.join(df2, F.col("id") == F.col("common_id"))
final_df.show(truncate=False)

final_cum_sum = final_df.withColumn('cumsum_balance', F.sum('balance').over(Window.partitionBy('common_id').orderBy('Date').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)))
final_cum_sum.show()
```

Following are all the outputs for your progressive understanding. I am not explaining the steps. You can figure them out.

```
Actual initial data
+-------+-----+-----+----------+
|From_Id|To_Id|Price|Date      |
+-------+-----+-----+----------+
|a      |b    |20   |2019-05-30|
|b      |c    |5    |2019-05-30|
|c      |a    |20   |2019-05-30|
|a      |d    |10   |2019-06-02|
|d      |c    |5    |2019-06-02|
+-------+-----+-----+----------+

Actual initial data
+---+--------+
|id |Name    |
+---+--------+
|a  |Claudia |
|b  |Manuella|
|c  |Remy    |
|d  |Paul    |
+---+--------+

+----------+---------+-------+
|Date      |common_id|initial|
+----------+---------+-------+
|2019-05-30|a        |0      |
|2019-05-30|d        |0      |
|2019-05-30|b        |0      |
|2019-05-30|c        |0      |
|2019-06-02|a        |0      |
|2019-06-02|d        |0      |
|2019-06-02|b        |0      |
|2019-06-02|c        |0      |
+----------+---------+-------+

+----------+---------+--------+
|Date      |common_id|from_sum|
+----------+---------+--------+
|2019-06-02|a        |10      |
|2019-05-30|a        |20      |
|2019-06-02|d        |5       |
|2019-05-30|c        |20      |
|2019-05-30|b        |5       |
+----------+---------+--------+

+----------+---------+-----------+
|Date      |common_id|from_amount|
+----------+---------+-----------+
|2019-06-02|a        |10         |
|2019-06-02|c        |0          |
|2019-05-30|a        |20         |
|2019-05-30|d        |0          |
|2019-06-02|b        |0          |
|2019-06-02|d        |5          |
|2019-05-30|c        |20         |
|2019-05-30|b        |5          |
+----------+---------+-----------+

+----------+---------+------+
|Date      |common_id|to_sum|
+----------+---------+------+
|2019-06-02|c        |5     |
|2019-05-30|a        |20    |
|2019-06-02|d        |10    |
|2019-05-30|c        |5     |
|2019-05-30|b        |20    |
+----------+---------+------+

+----------+---------+---------+
|Date      |common_id|to_amount|
+----------+---------+---------+
|2019-06-02|a        |0        |
|2019-06-02|c        |5        |
|2019-05-30|a        |20       |
|2019-05-30|d        |0        |
|2019-06-02|b        |0        |
|2019-06-02|d        |10       |
|2019-05-30|c        |5        |
|2019-05-30|b        |20       |
+----------+---------+---------+

+----------+---------+---------+-----------+
|Date      |common_id|to_amount|from_amount|
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+
|2019-06-02|a        |0        |10         |
|2019-06-02|c        |5        |0          |
|2019-05-30|a        |20       |20         |
|2019-05-30|d        |0        |0          |
|2019-06-02|b        |0        |0          |
|2019-06-02|d        |10       |5          |
|2019-05-30|c        |5        |20         |
|2019-05-30|b        |20       |5          |
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+

+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+
|Date      |common_id|to_amount|from_amount|balance|
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+
|2019-06-02|a        |0        |10         |-10    |
|2019-06-02|c        |5        |0          |5      |
|2019-05-30|a        |20       |20         |0      |
|2019-05-30|d        |0        |0          |0      |
|2019-06-02|b        |0        |0          |0      |
|2019-06-02|d        |10       |5          |5      |
|2019-05-30|c        |5        |20         |-15    |
|2019-05-30|b        |20       |5          |15     |
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+

+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+---+--------+
|Date      |common_id|to_amount|from_amount|balance|id |Name    |
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+---+--------+
|2019-05-30|a        |20       |20         |0      |a  |Claudia |
|2019-06-02|a        |0        |10         |-10    |a  |Claudia |
|2019-05-30|b        |20       |5          |15     |b  |Manuella|
|2019-06-02|b        |0        |0          |0      |b  |Manuella|
|2019-05-30|c        |5        |20         |-15    |c  |Remy    |
|2019-06-02|c        |5        |0          |5      |c  |Remy    |
|2019-06-02|d        |10       |5          |5      |d  |Paul    |
|2019-05-30|d        |0        |0          |0      |d  |Paul    |
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+---+--------+

+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+---+--------+--------------+
|      Date|common_id|to_amount|from_amount|balance| id|    Name|cumsum_balance|
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+---+--------+--------------+
|2019-05-30|        d|        0|          0|      0|  d|    Paul|             0|
|2019-06-02|        d|       10|          5|      5|  d|    Paul|             5|
|2019-05-30|        c|        5|         20|    -15|  c|    Remy|           -15|
|2019-06-02|        c|        5|          0|      5|  c|    Remy|           -10|
|2019-05-30|        b|       20|          5|     15|  b|Manuella|            15|
|2019-06-02|        b|        0|          0|      0|  b|Manuella|            15|
|2019-05-30|        a|       20|         20|      0|  a| Claudia|             0|
|2019-06-02|        a|        0|         10|    -10|  a| Claudia|           -10|
+----------+---------+---------+-----------+-------+---+--------+--------------+
```